# Connecting to Oracle 10g with ODBC from Excel VBA

Tags: oracle, excel, vba, odbc

The following code works. the connection opens fine but recordset.recordCount always returns -1 when there is data in the table. ANd If I try to call any methods/properties on recordset it crashes Excel. Any ideas??
Thanks

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.connection    
    Dim connString
    connString = "DSN=name;Uid=user;Pwd=pass"
    Dim rsRecords As New ADODB.recordSet

    conn.Open connString
    rsRecords.CursorLocation = adUseServer
    rsRecords.Open "select * from xxx", conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

    If conn.State = adStateOpen Then
      MsgBox rsRecords.RecordCount
    Else
       MsgBox "no connection"
    End If

    rsRecords.Close
    Set rsRecords = Nothing
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Recordcount to work, especially without fetching the records, you need to use `adUseClient` not `adUseServer`

If this is a large operation and you'll be doing it frequently, though, you should really select the count() instead and make the database do the counting for you. With `adUseClient` ADO will silently fetch all the records into your application's memory whether you like it or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Excel was crashing because it cannot handle some Oracle datatypes.
The select * was returning a column of type TIMESTAMP(3) WITH TIME ZONE.
This would cause Excel to crash as soon as I tried to read from the recordset.